# Link to an element after in ajax success method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So i make an ajax request for my form. It stores the information in the database, then the form is hidden and a thank you message is displayed. However i need the browser to snap up to the new thank you message.

So like on a normal page you can do something like this:

```
<a href="www.mywebsite.com/#test"></a>
<div id="test"></div>
```

So if you click that link it snaps you to the element.

How can i do this automatically in my ajax success method?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var messagePos = $("#test").offset();
window.scrollTo(0, messagePos.top);
```

The `offset()` function gets the element's position relative to the document. And then the `window.scrollTo()` function moves to a specified x and y position in the document. In this case, the x is 0, and the y is top of the message div.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, inside the success callback you would have to have something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#thankyou").offset().top
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

If you would want it to be smooth you would just change the `0` to a `500` (half a second).

Comment: You need to give me something more than, because this is working with me. What happens?

Comment: nothing happens, my javascript is in another file. But literally nothing happens.

Comment: Console errors, nothing? Well... you'd have to show me the success function because like this I wont be able to check if you're doing something wrong.